# Full domain url subfolder redirected my django application with apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've been facing the following problem. I got django 1.9 integrated with apache 2.4+ via mod_wsgi application. I run manage.py collectstatic and everything is fine when i use the root url.
`http//10.184.2.231`  it is ok and static files are served properly.

Actually i will be redirected to my django app from the link `www.mydomain.com/nuovopatetdb`

This is my configuration

```
from urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.search_ES,name='search_ES'),
    url(r'^nuovopatentdb$', views.search_ES,name='search_ES'), 
    url(r'^download/(?P<id_src>.*)$', views.send_file, name="download"),
    url(r"^documents$", views.documents,name="documents"),
]


#settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ES_Brevetti.wsgi.application'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'patentdb.apps.patentdbConfig',
    'mod_wsgi.server',
    'el_pagination',
]


#httpconf.d

Alias '/static' '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static'

<Directory '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static'>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

This is an example of  my template:

```
<div id="waitLoading" >
    <img src="{%static "images/giphy.gif"%}">
</div>
```

The image giphy.gif cannot be served and i get the3 follwoing error:
GET http://www.mydomain/static/images/giphy.gif 404 (Not Found)

How can i work this around?
Many many thanx for ur help

Comment: Does the file ``/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static/images/giphy.gif`` exist? Are the permissions of the file and parent directories such that the Apache user can read it.

Comment: Hi Graham thanx for your reply. Actually i run the following command line :  python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only  --port=80 --user elastic --group elastic --server-root=/home/elastic/mod_wsgi-express-80   and runining sudo ./apachectl start using the user elastic that is a sudoers. So yes the user elastic can access giphy.gif and yes it exists

Comment: Hi Graham, 

i want to claim that www.mydomain.com is not the FQDN of my server where django app + mod_swgi +apache is installed, but it's another server that redirect to my django app. Hope this clarifies.

thanx valerio

Comment: If you use the direct URL to the Django instance, rather than the site that does the redirect, can you get to the file?

Comment: Hi Graham, If i use "10.184.2.231/static/images/giphy.gif" i can get the resource. If i use "www.mydomain.com/static/images/giphy.gif" i canNOT get the resource.

Comment: If you say ``www.mydomain.com`` is another server, is that other server triggering a redirect, or trying to proxy. It sounds like it is the front end which is the issue, likely having incorrect of conflicting configuration.

Comment: Hi Graham , it is a kind of net address translation, where public address www.domain.com  is translated to 10.184.2.231 that is my local machine address. If i connect internally it works, connecting from outside world it doesn't. Any clue?

Comment: This is what i get on my log file: Fri Mar 10 12:57:59.573819 2017] 
[wsgi:error] [pid 4832:tid] The timeout specified has expired: [client] mod_wsgi (pid=4832): Failed to proxy response to client.

Comment: If the front end box is in a different network, it looks a bit like the network routing is not set up properly to allow the return traffic to get through.

Comment: Hi Graham is it possible the problem is only with staticfiles? The home page is loaded but static files are not!

Comment: Actually, that timeout shouldn't arise if you have correct Alias directive. That timeout means request went through to mod_wsgi daemon process, which the request shouldn't.

Comment: Hi Graham, i figured out the problem but not the the solution yet. www.mydomain.com/nuovopatentdb is my root url. If i get www.mydomain.com/nuovopatentdb/images/giphy.gif i get the resource. I have added Alias '/nuovopatentdb/static' '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static' The problem is that in my html template the source of the image is : www.mydomain.com/images/giphy.gif. Pratically i want nuovopatentdb to be added in the src of the template of all the static files.....

Comment: Pretically i want Django application mounted on a path other than the root of a domain in my case www.mydomain.com/nuovopatentdb

Comment: Mount it at the same sub URL on the backend. Otherwise you can try setting ``FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`` in Django settings file to make Django think it is at sub URL even though it isn't. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#force-script-name

Comment: No success with FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = /nuovopatentdb' in settings.py but i do think this should be a pretty common issue. Cannot find any solution on the web.

Comment: If I have got it right, try ``WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/wsgi.py/nuovopatentdb``. The ``FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`` should do something similar though if set up correctly.

Comment: I worked this out!  i set the image as the following:  <div id="waitLoading" >
    <img src="../nuovopatentdb/static/images/giphy.gif"%}">
</div>  . It's not elegant hardcode "nuovopatentdb" in the template, but in the future i will replace the subdirectory "nuovopatentdb" with a custom template variable. Anyway Graham i want to thank you very much for ur support.